# Sequel JOIN and WHERE

Tags: mysql, ruby, sequel

I have the following MySQL statement:

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    b.category,
    b.message,
    b.is_valid
FROM
    "NODE" a,
    "SYSTEM_STATUS" b
WHERE 
    ("LAST_HEARTBEAT" > TIMESTAMP '2017-09-18 15:10:04.471826') AND 
    a.id = b.node_id
```

I want to convert the above to Sequel

I have this method which is a reduce version of the above MySQL statement:

```
0> self.class.live_nodes

SELECT "ID" FROM "NODE" WHERE ("LAST_HEARTBEAT" > TIMESTAMP '2017-09-18 15:11:12.906017')

=> [#<MyApp::Model::Node @values={:id=>348}>]
```

Now, using the results of this method, I want to do a `join` with a table called `system_status`, where the results of `node.id = system_status.node_id`.

Next, I want to take the results of `live_nodes` and join it to `system_status` where the result is equal to `system_status.node_id`, and I am not sure how to do it.

I tried the following:

```
0> MyApp::Model::Node.where { last_heartbeat > Time.now - HEARTBEAT_TIMEOUT.seconds }.join(:system_status, :node_id, :id)
```

But received this error

```
=> no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
```

Not sure how to fix it.. I also don't think I am doing the aliasing correctly

Comment: Is your MySQL correct? Just from raw SQL I miss the join part in the SQL. (But I don't know MySQL, so it may by a special syntax from MySQL). The join could be build with `DB[:a].inner_join(:b,  :node_id => :id)` in sequel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are extremely close with the `join` but I believe it should be

```
# basically table_name, left_side, right_side
join(:system_status, node_id: :id)
```

For more explicit joins the following should also work

```
# Sequel > 4.38.0
join(:system_status, node_id: Sequel[:nodes][:id])
# Sequel < 4.39.0
join(:system_status, node_id: Sequel.expr(:nodes__id))
```

This should generate

```
INNER JOIN system_status ON system_status.node_id = nodes.id
```

Comment: Hm, it looks like I got the following error when I used `Sequel[..]`: `undefined method '[]' for Sequel:Module`

Comment: @theGreenCabbage hmm that is strange since the [Docs](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/cheat_sheet_rdoc.html#label-Joins) seem to suggest that is exactly how it should work and  [`Sequel#[]`](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/lib/sequel/core.rb#L404) is an alias for [`Sequel#expr`](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/lib/sequel/sql.rb#L447)

Comment: Looks like we're using an older version of Sequel because your new solution worked - thank you =)!

Comment: Second small question - how could I select the `system_status.message`, `node.id`, etc? Basically how do I define the table before the column I want to grab?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage in newer versions `Sequel[:table][:column]` but you can use `Sequel#expr` syntax just as I did above `Sequel.expr(:system_status__message)` . The syntax is very simple table name 2 underscores column name three underscores alias (optional) e.g. `:system_status__message___notation` will be `system_status.message as notation`. Additionally RawSQL is always an option as well. Here is a nice [Cheat Sheet](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/cheat_sheet_rdoc.html) but it applies to the current version so it is possible not everything will work perfectly for you.